# c# Searching for a string that contains quotes

Tags: c#, file, search, .net-assembly

I am fairly new to c# and am working on a little project but got stuck on this. I have a file that contains some assembly code. I want my program to search this file for a string, actually a value right after my string. One of the strings i am searching for is:

```
setproperty         QName(PackageNamespace(""), "font")

  getlocal            4
  pushint
```

My search code is this:

```
private void searchFile(String searchText)
    {
       System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file);
       String text = reader.ReadToEnd();
       if (Regex.IsMatch(text, searchText))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(searchText + " was  found in the given file", "Finally!!");
        }
       else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, but " + searchText + " could not be found in the given file", "No Results");
        }
    }

    //when i click a button//
    searchFile(@"setproperty         QName(PackageNamespace(""""), ""font"")

  getlocal            4
  pushint             ");
```

I know that the string is in the file but the result comes up with not found. I don't know if it is the quotes or tabs or both that is causing this.

Here is part of the file:

```
getlocal            4
  pushstring          "Verdana"
  setproperty         QName(PackageNamespace(""), "font")

  getlocal            4
  pushint             16764170
  setproperty         QName(PackageNamespace(""), "color")

  getlocal            4
  pushbyte            12
  setproperty         QName(PackageNamespace(""), "size")
```

My second question is how can i get the value of the first int after my search result?

Thanks in advance.

-Leen

Answer (score 2):

You should change your method like this:

```
private static string searchFile(String searchText)
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("test.txt");
        String text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        int poz = text.IndexOf(searchText);
        if (poz >= 0)
        {                
            int start = poz + searchText.Length;
            int end = text.IndexOf("\n", start);   
            Console.WriteLine(searchText + " was  found in the given file", "Finally!!");
            return text.Substring(start, end - start);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, but " + searchText + " could not be found in the given file", "No Results");
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

The call:

```
string val = searchFile("setproperty         QName(PackageNamespace(\"\"), \"font\")\r\n\r\n  getlocal            4\r\n  pushint             ");
```

Comment: Thanks so much, It did not quite work right away but i managed to fix that by changing the search string to : string val = searchFile("setproperty         QName(PackageNamespace(\"\"), \"font\")\n\n      getlocal            4\n      pushint             ");. It actually finds the string now. I still have one error.                 return text.Substring(start, end - start);
 comes up with : Length cannot be less than zero.

Comment: you could try with this new version

Answer (score 0):

So I think you may be use to VB.net. C-based languages (like c#) used the backslash character "\" as an escape character.
So in a searching for a double-quote in a string you would need to escape it using \".

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
searchFile(@"setproperty         QName(PackageNamespace(\"\"), \"font\")

  getlocal            4
  pushint             ");
```

But this isn't really a regular expression, which is what the Regex class is meant for.  So I would (well not really, I would clean it up a bit, like not mix my UI and bizlogic) do this:

```
// Added String as the function type so you can return the matched "Integer" as a string, you could always do a Int32.TryParse(...)
private String searchFile(String file, String searchText)
{
    System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file);
    String text = reader.ReadToEnd();

    int32 index = text.IndexOf(searchText);

    if (index >= 0) //We could find it at the very beginning
    {
        MessageBox.Show(searchText + " was found in the given file", "Finally!!");

        int32 start = index + searchText.Length;
        int32 end = Regex.Match(text, "[\n\r\t]", index).Index; // This will search for whitespace

        String value = text.Substring(start, end - start);
        // Now you can do something with your value, like...
        return value;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, but " + searchText + " could not be found in the given file", "No Results");
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Having the search string like you have it will give a new line in constant error.

Comment: " are escaped with "" in C# if it's a verbatim string literal (ie  @"...")

Comment: @Leon - Sorry I didn't test this in VS.  I wrote it in notepad.  You might use londens search string.